# Error Uploading to AWS S3 via POST in browser?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3, file-upload

Based On The [AWS in Browser-Based Uploads Using POST](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-UsingHTTPPOST.html) Docs, I'm attempting to upload audio files to my bucket without having to pull in an entire SDK. I'm using **Vue.js**. When I make a request, here is the **error** I get back:

> ```
> <Error>
>    <Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
>    <Message>The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.</Message>
>    <RequestId>7FE397A138CF89</RequestId>
>    <HostId>rEx4jk6vj363wlVGrGqutyDkMNeUhi6DizAXhAiIWrIpG8Rups1rLFGO4Dge5loeNj</HostId>
> </Error>
> ```

**CODE TO CREATE A POLICY, SIGNING KEY & SIGNATURE**

**Policy Func** - creates JSON obj of conditions & returns Utf-8 & Base64 encoded version (as per [AWS Doc's](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html#sigv4-PolicyConditions))

```
getPolicy (date) {
    let moment = this.$moment(date) // using moment.js
    let formattedDate = moment.format('YYYYMMDD')

    let obj = { 
        "expiration": date,
        "conditions": [
            {"bucket": "test-bucket"},
            {"acl": "public-read"},
            {"key": "test.mp3"},
            ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "audio/"],
            ["content-length-range", 1048579, 3000000000],
            {"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"},
            {"x-amz-credential": `KJIAI4OQHKZGIBSQY5TQ/${formattedDate}/us-east-2/s3/aws4_request`},
            {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
            {"x-amz-date": formatedDate}
        ]
    }
    let string = JSON.stringify(obj)
    let utf8 = encodeURI(string)
    let base64 = btoa(utf8)
    return base64   
}
```

**Signing Key Func** - creates an HmacSHA256 Signing Key (as per [AWS Doc's](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-javascript))

```
getSigningKey (date) {
    // AWSSecretAccessKeyId (obviously this is a dummy)
    let key = '+eo98jdkXTjOYO2weY84m2vzCV63vMI6yGvC097R'

    let dateKey = crypto.HmacSHA256(date, `AWS4${key}`)
    let dateRegionKey = crypto.HmacSHA256('us-east-2', dateKey)
    let dateRegionServiceKey = crypto.HmacSHA256('s3', dateRegionKey)
    let signingKey = crypto.HmacSHA256('aws4_request', dateRegionServiceKey)

    return signingKey.toString()
}
```

**Signature Func** - creates a hex-encoded, HmacSHA256 signature (as per [AWS Doc's](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html#signing-request-intro))

```
getSignature (date) {
    let policy = this.getPolicy(date)
    let signingKey = this.getSigningKey(date)
    let signature = crypto.HmacSHA256(policy, signingKey)
    let hexEncodedSignature = signature.toString(hex)

    return hexEncodedSignature
}
```

**AJAX REQUEST MADE USING AXIOS**

```
uploadFile (file) {
    const date = new Date().toISOString()
    let moment = this.$moment(date)
    let formattedDate = b.format('YYYYMMDD')

    const policy = this.getPolicy(date)
    const signature = this.getSignature(date)

    const form = new FormData()
    form.append('key', 'test.mp3')
    form.append('acl', 'public-read')
    form.append('Content-Type', 'audio/*')
    form.append('x-amz-server-side-encryption', 'AES256')
    form.append('X-Amz-Credential', `KJIAI4OQHKZGIBSQY5TQ/${formattedDate}/us-east-2/s3/aws4_request`)
    form.append('X-Amz-Algorithm', 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256')
    form.append('X-Amz-Date', formattedDate)
    form.append('AWSAccessKeyId', 'KJIAI4OQHKZGIBSQY5TQ')
    form.append('Policy', policy)
    form.append('Signature', signature)
    form.append('file', file)

    return axios.post('https://test-bucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/', form).then((response) => {
         // do something
    }
```

WHAT AM I DOING WRONG TO RECEIVE THE RESPONSE ERROR?

Comment: One thing that appears to be wrong is that you are using the same date format in both X-Amz-Credential and X-Amz-Date. The former is valid but I think the latter should in ISO 8601 format (YYYYMMDD'T'HHMMSS'Z'). For example, 20190414T202100Z.

Comment: @jarmod even after making that change, the error persist

Comment: You've also indicated 'Signature' which the sigv4 POST example documentation shows as 'X-Amz-Signature'. It also looks like the first step of generating the signing key should be UTF-8 encoded (not sure that's a problem here but just pointing out places where your code appears to diverge).  I'd recommend a very careful re-read of the docs at this point.

Comment: Additionally, remove `AWSAccessKeyId` from the form.  You have a mix of Sig V2 and Sig V4.

Comment: when I remove `AWSAccessKeyId` I get the following error: 
`Bucket POST must contain a field named 'AWSAccessKeyId'.  If it is specified, please check the order of the fields.` @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: Consider that error to caused by the *presence* of a different field -- specifically, `Signature` -- which should not be here either, as @jarmod indicated above.

Comment: @RobertTillman iterating on this one field at a time and trying to understand what the next error message means is probably not ideal. You're going to get, and in fact have gotten, misleading error messages because of the (incorrect) presence of some other field. Signing is not a trivial process which is why most people rely on the AWS SDKs to do it. If you can't use the SDKs then you'll have to carefully follow the documentation.

Comment: after removing `AWSAccessKeyId` I know just get the error: 
`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.` @jarmod